# Sharepoint 2016: Hide folders in search results

Tags: 2016, search-results, content-query-web-part, folder

As I am working through the site and building it, I have come across a small issue I wish to fix.

My current setup, which works for our site well, is using a "Vault" system.
One document library with many folders and files. I then use content query to pull certain files to certain pages. This works great.

The problem is, when someone searches for a document, more often than not the directory the document is in appears either at the top or very near the top of the search results.
[image]

I am trying to hide all folders from appearing and only showing documents or pages, no need to show any document library, lists, sub-sites or folders.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

**For Content Query Webpart**:

1. Open the tool pane of your webpart.
2. Expand **Query** and navigate to **Content Type** section.
3. Select **Document Content Types** under **Show items of this content type group** dropdown.
4. Select **Document** under **Show items of this content type** dropdown.
5. Check **Include child content types** checkbox.
6. Click **Apply** and then **OK**.

[image]

**For Content Search Webpart**:

Add below to your search query:

**To show only documents**:

```
IsDocument:true
```

**To show site pages (`.aspx` files)**:

```
FileType:aspx
```

**Reference**: [Limit search results to “Documents”](https://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/limit-search-results-to-documents.html).

Comment: Thank you. However how do I implement this?
I've gone over all the settings I can find. I am not using a webpart, this is to change the site search when they use the search bar in the top right of the page.

Comment: Check updated answer for content query webpart.

Comment: Again thank you. But doesn't this only apply to a webpart?
Ideally I want the search bar which is on the top right of every sharepoint page to exclude folders.
Updated original post to show this.

Comment: Yes, this is applied to a particular content query webpart. You mentioned that you are pulling files using content query webpart in your question.

Comment: Correct. But that (which I should of explained) is purely for visual use for those using the site. People will still use the search bar in the top right when they can't find something. 
I'm more disappointed that there doesn't seem to be a way of filtering these results. The end user sees everything in the search, behind the curtain so to speak. Even the search bar webpart can't be customised to allow custom queries.

Comment: Yes. But users can see only the documents or folders to which they have access. So, you need to manage that using permissions.